# GoCD stage to run a script if it exists

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, go-cd

I have a template that all my pipelines are using.

id like to add the stage to run a contract-tests.sh file.

not all my projects will have this file so there pipelines break.

I do not want to create a new template

I tried the following custom command as a test but it does not actually echo the line to the console.

`test -f contract-tests.sh && echo "contract tests file is present"`

Answer (score 0):

GoCD's commands are not run through a shell by default, so you'll have to explicitly call executable `/bin/sh` with the arguments `-c` and `test -f contract-tests.sh && echo "contract tests file is present"`

You also need to make sure the command is run in the directory where the script actually is (which is certainly not the project's root directory if you have more than one material, for example).

Another possible trick to only run a command in some cases and not others is to put the command name in a `param` of the template. That way you can provide `contract-tests.sh` as the param for pipelines that have it, and a dummy like `/bin/true` or `echo` for pipelines that don't.